# Vaadin MVP button click not working

Tags: java, vaadin

I am new in Vaadin and I have a problem.

I have tried with this: https://vaadin.com/web/magi/home/-/blogs/model-view-presenter-pattern-with-vaadin and example app is ok, but when I try to create something similar it's not working for me.

I have a simple login form (login, password fields, and one button). And there is a problem with the button. It's not triggered. I can click but the action is not started.

Here is my code:

```
public interface LoginView {
    public void getNotification(String text);

    interface LoginViewListener{
        void loginButtonClick(String login, String password);
    }

    public void addListener(LoginViewListener listener);
}

public class LoginViewImpl extends CustomComponent implements LoginView,Button.ClickListener {

    private TextField loginField = new TextField();
    private PasswordField passwordField = new PasswordField();
    private Label loginLabel = new Label("Login:");
    private Label passwordLabel = new Label("Password:");
    private Button loginButton = new Button("Login");

    LoginViewListener listener;

    public LoginViewImpl(){
        VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();
        layout.setSizeFull();
        layout.addComponent(loginLabel);
        layout.addComponent(loginField);
        layout.addComponent(passwordLabel);
        layout.addComponent(passwordField);
        layout.addComponent(loginButton);
        setCompositionRoot(layout);
    }

    public void getNotification(String text){
        Notification.show(text);
    }

    @Override
    public void buttonClick(Button.ClickEvent event) {
        listener.loginButtonClick("jeden","dwa");
    }


    public void addListener(LoginViewListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }
}

public class LoginModel {
    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    private String login;
    private String password;
}


public class LoginPresenter implements LoginView.LoginViewListener {
    LoginModel model;
    LoginView view;

    public LoginPresenter(LoginModel model, LoginView view){
        this.model = model;
        this.view = view;

        view.addListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void loginButtonClick(String login, String password) {
        view.getNotification(login + " " + password);
    }
}

@SpringUI(path = "")
public class MainClass extends UI {

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
        LoginModel model = new LoginModel();
        LoginViewImpl view = new LoginViewImpl();

        new LoginPresenter(model, view);

        VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();

        layout.setSizeFull();
        layout.addComponent(view);
        setContent(layout);
    }
}
```

Can you tell me what's wrong? :(

Comment: addClickListener() is missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `LoginViewImpl` doesn't listen to the `loginButton` events.

Check out how buttons are created in [the MVP tutorial](https://vaadin.com/web/magi/home/-/blogs/model-view-presenter-pattern-with-vaadin):

```
// Add buttons and have them send click events
// to this class
for (String caption: operations)
    layout.addComponent(new Button(caption, this));
```

Notice the usage of [a Button constructor overload](https://vaadin.com/api/7.7.6/com/vaadin/ui/Button.html#Button-java.lang.String-com.vaadin.ui.Button.ClickListener-) which accepts `ClickListener`. This way view implementation is registered as a handler of buttons' click events.

You should do something similar in your code:

```
public LoginViewImpl(){
    //skip
    loginButton.addClickListener(this);
    layout.addComponent(loginButton);
    setCompositionRoot(layout);
}
```

Comment: Just click listener... Thank you very much! :)